# Saving V4L2 video camera output

Tags: linux, video-capture, video-encoding, v4l2

What video format would be the easiest when saving the output of a camera using V4L2 if I capture it in bitmap format? Getting mpeg directly could be, of course, nice, but I can't unfortunately count on that.

I have managed to capture the frames, now I need to somehow view the video. Can I simply convert those frames using some Linux tool or could I save the video easily straight from my app?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad, didn't notice that you were talking about 'my app' so this is actually programming related - in any case, libffmpeg is probably a thing worth looking at in any case...

Comment: Well, let's put it this way: it's a "device" and I need to write a code that simply verifies that the camera (among others) works. The video format doesn't need to be fancy or anything, it's enough if I can demonstrate that it was the camera that actually grabbed the video. So part of the problem is I don't know if I can install lots of non-standard libraries (e.g. ones that are not in Linux already) to the device.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple (as in a Proof-of-Concept demo), you can go ahead and directly store the YUV frames captured from the device into a file.

There are a bunch of viewers that support playback of single/multiple frame(s) of YUV data from a file.

One such YUV viewer is [**freecode.com/projects/yay**](http://freecode.com/projects/yay)

Answer (score -1):

You could use practically any format/codec if you used [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html) or [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

<strike>Btw, this question really should be on superuser.com</strike>

Answer (score -1):

If you are capturing frames already, you could save them to PPM images and then go to JPEG.  I did this using v4l2 and ImageMagick.  Maybe you could push JPEGs into a Motion JPEG stream.  It might not be as high tech as MPEG, but you might get it working quickly.  PPM files were a cinch to create.  If I remember correctly, the v4l2 example code shows you how to do that part.

Comment: There is no such thing in the capture.c example found in the V4L2 spec.

Comment: Well, thanks for that...it's been a long time.  I found an example on some v4l2 related site.  It's not like he asked for PPM specific code examples.